# Making a concat operator to add char array to a string. Printing a reference variable of a string object

Tags: java, arrays

So far, if I try to use the concat operator I get this error
Tester.java:14: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method concat(MyString)
location: class MyString
    System.out.println(hello.concat(goodbye)); // prints "hellogoodbye"

and when I try to print the "hello" object of MyString I get MyString@558ee9d6
I feel like its soo close to working..

```
public class MyString

{
     private char[] charString;
     private String oneString;


      public  MyString(String string) 
      {
        this.oneString = string;


      }

//second constructor for overloading
    public MyString(char[] s) 
    {

        this.charString = s;
        this.oneString = charString.toString();
    }

//methods
    public String toString( char [] s)
    {
        return new String(s);
    }

    public char charAt(int i) {

        char [] temp = new char[oneString.length()];
        for ( int j = 0; j < oneString.length() ;  j++)
        temp[j] = oneString.charAt(i);
        return temp[i];
    }

    public String concat ( char[] s)
    {
        s.toString();
        String result = oneString + s;
        return result;
    }

    public String concat ( String s)
    {
        String result = oneString + s;
        return result;
    }


}
```

public class Tester
{
public static void main (String[] args)

```
    {
    MyString hello = new MyString("hello");
    System.out.println(hello);  // right now this prints MyString@558ee9d6
    System.out.println(hello.charAt(0));    // works, prints 'h'
    char[] arr = {'g','o','o','d','b','y','e' };
    MyString goodbye = new MyString(arr);
   // System.out.println(hello.concat(goodbye)); // i can't get this line to work
    System.out.println(hello.equals(goodbye)); // works, prints false
    System.out.println(hello.equals(hello));  //works, prints true
    }
    }
```

Comment: You should probably proofread your code a little bit before posting it. There are a lot of problems that a simple compile could help you with.

Comment: The internal `charString` is that required? It's just complicating your internal state, keeping just a `String` makes it much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to print an Object :

```
System.out.println(hello);  // right now this prints MyString@558ee9d6
```

In this case your MyString class

Make the get method to your variable oneString.

```
public String getOneString() {return this.oneString;}
```

and then call

```
System.out.println(hello.getOneString());
```

Another problem

```
System.out.println(hello.concat(goodbye));
```

You concat method receives a string and not a MyString class

You may want to do this

```
System.out.println(hello.concat(goodbye.getOneString()));
```

or

```
public String concat ( MyString myS)
    {
        String s = myS.getOneString();
        String result = oneString + s;
        return result;
    }
```

Final result:

```
public class Tester { public static void main (String[] args)

    {
    MyString hello = new MyString("hello");
    System.out.println(hello.getOneString());
    System.out.println(hello.getOneString().charAt(0)); 
    char[] arr = {'g','o','o','d','b','y','e' };
    MyString goodbye = new MyString(arr);
    System.out.println(hello.concat(goodbye.getOneString()));
    System.out.println(hello.equals(goodbye)); // works, prints false
    System.out.println(hello.equals(hello));  //works, prints true
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`charString.toString()` will give you the `String` representation of the `char[]` object, it won't convert your `char[]` into a `String`.

If you want/need that `oneString` attribute contains the `String` representation of your `charString`, then you could create a `String` using your char array:

```
this.oneString = new String(charString);
```

Also, this line

```
System.out.println(hello);
```

would print the `String` representation of your object. You need to override the `public String toString()` method in `Object` class in your `MyString` class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.oneString; //or similar
}
```

Comment: do you know why does do i get a "cannot find symbol" error for concat when i try to run it?

Comment: @FredV that's because your `concat` method receives a `char[]` or a `String` parameter, not a `MyString`, and you have `MyString goodbye`.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that right now, you are trying to add a character array to a string. Calling s.toString() wouldn't make the char[] a String. That won't work the way you have it. Try

```
result = oneString + new String(s);
```